# IServiceCollection class unresolved

Tags: c#, service, asp.net-core

Below is my `Startup.cs` class :

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using MapApp.Models;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MapApp.Startup))]

namespace MapApp
{

public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    } 
}
}
```

The problem is that the `IServiceCollection` is unresolved : underlined in red.

I am following the steps in the link : https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html#add-a-model-class

Comment: Did you add a reference in your project to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` and add a using directive for the namespace, like `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`?  Usually if something is underlined in red you're either missing a reference or a `using` directive.

Comment: You are mixing up OWIN and Dot.Net Core. Check the documentation here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/owin.html

Comment: @Nkosi : What do you mean ? Can you be more explicit ?

Comment: Check the documentation linked in my previous comment. What type of project is it? asp.net-core?

Comment: Okay, thank you. But one thing, I can't find the file `project.json` Fyi, I'm now working locally on a test project. I am using VS2015

Comment: Based on the link in OP's question, it's ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

The skeleton that you're looking for is this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MapApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        { 

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what referred you to the `Owin` assemblies.